# NSObject inherited class crashes the application

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new in objective-C and here is my problem:
I want to write a game and i want to use a GameStateManager class to manage the game states. As i've read every class in Objective-C should be inherited from NSObject or it's subclass. So here is the GameStateManager interface:

```
@interface GameStateManager : NSObject {
    int currentState_;
}
+(id) instance;
-(void) setState:(int)state;

@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
@implementation GameStateManager
+(id) instance
{
    GameStateManager *manager = [GameStateManager init];
return manager;
}

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
return self;
}

- (void) setState: (int) state
{
switch (state)
{
    case GS_MAIN_MENU_START:
    {
//          MenuScene *menuScene = [MenuScene node];
//          [menuScene build: false];
        MenuScene *scene = [scene instance:self :false];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: scene];  
    }
        break;

    case GS_PLAYING:
    {

    }
        break;
}
}

@end
```

I use this class here:

```
gameStateManager = [GameStateManager instance];
[gameStateManager setState: GS_MAIN_MENU_START];
```

The second line generated an SIGABRT signal. What's the problem ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a singleton. If that's true, you're doing it the wrong way. Additionally, check your memory management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
+ (id) instance
{
    GameStateManager *manager = [GameStateManager init];
    return manager;
}
```

In effect you are calling `init` without ever calling `alloc`. I’d recommend that you forget about the `instance` stuff and use the official `init` patterns until you are really comfortable with the memory management:

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;
    …
    return self;
}
```

…and then get your instance by calling `[[GameStateManager alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
GameStateManager *manager = [GameStateManager init];
```

`-(id)init` is an instance method, not a class method. That line should look like this:

```
GameStateManager *manager = [[GameStateManager alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hm, that's a memory leak unless you declare `manager` to be static, and check to see if it's already created before calling `+alloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the gameStateManager isn't being created properly. Instead of

```
[GameStateManager init]
```

use

```
[[[GameStateManager alloc] init] autorelease]
```

The autorelease is for good memory management and doesn't actually affect the initialization.

Comment: You're answer seems to suggest that the *autorelease* is needed for what he tries to achieve. I know that's not what you wanted to say, but it just looks like this.

Comment: I realized that, and that's why I explicitly said it it's just for good memory management.  But thanks for formatting that better for me, I was on an iPad.  StackOverflow wasn't really made for iPads.